# newspaper article ArticleException

Tags: heroku, python-newspaper

When I test the different requests of my API locally it works but when I host it on Heroku I get an error:

```
newspaper.article.ArticleException: Article `download()` failed with Exceeded 30 redirects. on URL
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. It's really hard to answer your question without more detailed information. Please read the guideline on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more advice.

Comment: Thanks I resolve my problem yesterday. i was used a free account on Heroku, so when I paid a hobby account, my problem disappear

Comment: Thanks I resolve my problem yesterday. i was used a free account on Heroku, so when I paid a hobby account, my problem disappear